# Mongoose One to Many relatioship

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to create a one to many relationship between `Category` and `Services` models.

I have two schemas: `Category` and `Service`.

`Category` schema holds `services` array.

`Service` schema hold `category` _id.

I'm trying to retrieve all `Categories` including `services`.

`Category` schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const categoriesModel = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        category: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        services: [{ type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'Service' }],
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

export const Category = mongoose.model('Category', categoriesModel);
```

`Service` schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const serviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        serviceName: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        images: {
            type: Array,
            image: Buffer,
            required: true,
        },
        category: {
            type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Category',
            required: true,
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

export const Service = mongoose.model('Service', serviceSchema);
```

HTTP get request to retrieve all `Categories` including `Services`:

```
export const getAllCategories = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const docs = await Category.find({}).populate({
            path: 'services',
            model: 'Service',
        });
        console.log(docs);
        res.status(200).json({ data: docs });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json(err.message);
    }
};
```

This is what I get as a response from the request above:

```
  {
            "services": [],
            "_id": "60affe06c71901281d3d820d",
            "category": "Electricity"
  },
```

I've tried different ways to `populate` `services` but none of them worked.

What I've tried so far:

1. Add additional nesting to `services` attribute.
2. Adding object to the `populate` params:

   ```
   {
            path: 'services',
            model: 'Service',
   }
   ```
3. Removing existing data ant posting additional one.

Fun fact. Retrieving each `Service` individually, `service` data includes the actual category, that it's been assigned to:

```
 export const getAllServices = async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const doc = await Service.find({}).populate('category');
            res.status(200).json({ data: doc });
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(400).json(err);
        }
    };
```

Is there something I'm missing regarding including `services` within retrieving `categories`? It's really interesting, because somehow the actual `services` data is `[]`.

**EDIT**: Each `category` in `Categories` collection has empty `services` array. The `services` are added dynamically, they might be `null` for specific `category` until user adds a service and assigns a `category` to it. Is this forbidden? Do I need to find specific `category` and add a specific `service` to `category` while creating new `service`? If yes, this would require to add additional `Category` model to the `services.controller.js` and find the `category`. Is this really an appropriate solution?

Comment: You are using double-referencing. adding a service to the services collection with a ref to a category will NOT automatically update the category document with a ref to services. you'll need to find the relevant category document and update it yourself.

Comment: Big thanks for the response! I really needed it! I had some thoughts about the solution you have just suggested but I was wondering about the fact that my `services.controller.js` will be too much coupled. So is it good practice to use multiple schemas in a single controller?